# filter table rows within range of related column

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgres database with the following table:

```
    CREATE TABLE data (
      id integer PRIMARY KEY,
      group_id integer NOT NULL,
      value double
    );
```

the data contained in it is like the following:

```
| id  | group_id | value |
| --- | -------- | ----- |
| 1   | 1        | 0     |
| 3   | 1        | 0.6   |
| 4   | 1        | 1     |
| 2   | 1        | 2     |
| 33  | 1        | 5     |
| 7   | 2        | 0.0   |
| 11  | 2        | 0.1   |
| 6   | 2        | 0.33  |
| 8   | 2        | 1.5   |
| 20  | 2        | 2     |
```

I need to get all the rows in a group_id between two id's values.
For example for the **group_id 2** and **ids 11 and 8** I should get:

```
| 11  | 2        | 0.1   |
| 6   | 2        | 0.33  |
| 8   | 2        | 1.5   |
```

I was looking for a cleaner solution than:

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM 
  data
WHERE
  group_id = 2 AND
value BETWEEN (SELECT value FROM data  WHERE id = 11)
      AND (SELECT value FROM data  WHERE id = 8)
```

and that possibly worked if the ids are reversed, like for the **group_id 2** and **ids 8 and 11** returned:

```
| 8   | 2        | 1.5   |
| 6   | 2        | 0.33  |
| 11  | 2        | 0.1   |
```

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vEBk4PdLPB2q9skt6UEG1u/0)

```
with user_defined_params as (
  select 2 as target_group_id,
  8 as first_id,
  11 as second_id
),
target_value_bounds AS (
  select min(value) as minval, max(value) as maxval
  from data where group_id=(select target_group_id from user_defined_params)
  AND ((id=(select first_id from user_defined_params))
       OR (id=(select second_id from user_defined_params)))
)
select * from data
where group_id=(select target_group_id from user_defined_params)
           AND value >= (select minval from target_value_bounds)
           AND value <= (select maxval from target_value_bounds);
```

If you're using this from a programming language, you'll definitely want to do away with the user_defined_params CTE and just use named query parameters.

Answer (score 0):

First Postgre desn't know double, that is quite strange.

But you need onyl to add a ORDER BY clause

> ```
>     CREATE TABLE data (
>       id integer PRIMARY KEY,
>       group_id integer NOT NULL,
>       value float
>     );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO data
>   ("id", "group_id", "value")
> VALUES
>   ('1', '1', '0'),
>   ('3', '1', '0.6'),
>   ('4', '1', '1'),
>   ('2', '1', '2'),
>   ('33', '1', '5'),
>   ('7', '2', '0.0'),
>   ('11', '2', '0.1'),
>   ('6', '2', '0.33'),
>   ('8', '2', '1.5'),
>   ('20', '2', '2');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
> "id", "group_id", "value"
> FROm 
> data
> WHERE "group_id" = 2 AND value BETWEEN (SELECT value FROM data  WHERE id = 11)
>       AND (SELECT value FROM data  WHERE id = 8)
> ORDER BY value
> ```
>
> ```
> id | group_id | value
> -: | -------: | :----
> 11 |        2 | 0.1  
>  6 |        2 | 0.33 
>  8 |        2 | 1.5
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=faba48653b681dec62ae1a8115248f1f)*